# If $x$ is a rational number prove the equation $x-[x] + x^2-[x^2] = 1$ has no answers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x$ is a rational number prove the equation $x-[x] + x^2-[x^2] = 1$ has no answers.

---

I’ve tried setting $x=a/b$ and $a=bk+r$ but it hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The equation $\{x^2\} + \{x\}=1$ has no solution over positive rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821794/the-equation-x2-x-1-has-no-solution-over-positive-rationals)

Comment: Note that while the linked dupe is only over _positive_ rationals, many if not all the resulting solutions work over all rationals when using the convention $\{t\} = t - [t]$ which connects directly to your question (not everyone uses that as the definition of the fractional part of negative real numbers, which might have been why the problem is restricted to positive rationals in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

(hope it helps) you can take $$x=n+p ,  \ n=[x] , \ 0\le p <1$$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c \to p=0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots \not =0 $ now lets rewrite equation $$x-[x]+x^2-[x^2]=1\\n+p-n+(n+p)^2-[(n+p)^2]=1\\p+n^2+2np+p^2-[n^2+2np+p^2]=1\\p+2np+p^2-[2np+p^2]=1\\p+p^2+2np=\underbrace{[2np+p^2]+1}_{\in \mathbb{Z}}$$  now show that there is not $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can satisfy above equation